# Why the $g_{00}$ of the Robetson-Walker metric is 1?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

Why it not depends on another variable?

Comment: What other variables could/would it depend on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values of individual entries in the metric tensor depend on the coordinate system you choose. In the case of the FLRW metric there is a natural choice of coordinates called the [comoving coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comoving_distance#Comoving_coordinates). In particular the comoving time has a very simple interpretation because it is equal to the proper time of a stationary observer, which obviously means $g_{00} = 1$.

So $g_{00}$ is equal to one because we've deliberately chosen coordinates where it is equal to one.